# Power Mockito WhenNew does'nt work

Tags: mocking, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

So I have a class to be tested which has a Constructor -

```
public class IdRunnable{
    public IdRunnable(Node root) {
            this.saHandler = new Handler(root);
    }

    public void call(){
    //Somes codes 
    }
}
```

I am using Powermock framework to inject the mock object when the new operator is called. The testing class is-

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({IdRunnable.class,Handler.class})
public class IdRunnableTest { 
    private IdRunnable runnable;

    @BeforeClass
    public void oneTimeSetUp(){
        Node root = new Node();
        Handler handler = mock(Handler.class);
        whenNew(Handler.class).withArguments(root).thenReturn(handler);
        runnable = new IdRunnable(root);
    }

    @Test(groups = {TestGroup.UNIT_TESTS})
    public void testCall(){
        runnable.call();
    }
}
```

When I run the test I can see that instead of mocking the new statement in IdRunnable's constructor It goes on create the real Handler Object.
Somehow the code-

```
whenNew(Handler.class).withArguments(root).thenReturn(handler);
```

does not work for me. Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Does work if you change your matcher: `whenNew(Handler.class).withArguments(Mockito.any(Node.class)).thenReturn(handler);`?

Answer (score 1):

Of course that is possible; but such a waste of energy.

Just do:

```
public IdRunnable(Node root) {
   this(new Handler(root);
}

IdRunnable(Handler saHandler) {
   this.saHandler = saHandler;
}
```

and your "need" to turn to PowerMock just vanishes. And yes, not *needing* PowerMock is a good thing. Because now you can use a constructor that allows you injecting that object that you need to mock.

Because it means that you prefer to write testable code. In my experience:

1. Powermock sometimes offers ugly surprises (such as test cases failing all of a sudden with obscure problems; not at all rooted in production code bugs)
2. It can be easily avoided, by learning how to create [testable](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) code.

Edit: given your comment; your only choice is to get PowerMock(ito) working for you. Probably this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169684/mocking-of-a-constructor-which-gives-the-base-class-reference-using-powermockito/41169830#41169830) of mine helps. It contains a small example for mocking constructor calls; shouldn't be a big deal to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I am not allowed to refactore the exisitng code as this is a legacy code I am working on. Any idea on how this can be achieved without refactoring the code base

Comment: Too bad. Still, I put an update for you in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Ghost...Its working when I am replacing testng annotations-     @BeforeClass and @Test(groups = {TestGroup.UNIT_TESTS}) with junit annotations. Any idea how to make Powermock compatible with testng.

Comment: Thanks. Btw: I think you should put the content of your last comment into your question. The question should always reflect all the information you have; you should not expect later readers to go through all the content to understand what is going on.